# Modify code that splits a worksheet based on column values to also copy an existing worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with two worksheets
1) Data source - normal table with multiple columns containing the data headers and rows containing the data
2) Summary tables and graphs that help to visualize the data on the first sheet depending on the dropdown select

I want to:
a) copy the data source and split into different workbooks based on a particular column value - I have code for this already
b) copy the summary table to each of the new workbooks - this is the part I can't figure out

This the code I have. I didn't write this myself, but I've been trying to insert a line that copies the worksheet with the summary tables into the new workbooks as well but I can't figure out what/where to put it.

```
Public Sub SplitToFiles()

' MACRO SplitToFiles
' Last update: 2019-05-28
' Author: mtone
' Version 1.2
' Description:
' Loops through a specified column, and split each distinct values into a separate file by making a copy and deleting rows below and above
'
' Note: Values in the column should be unique or sorted.
'
' The following cells are ignored when delimiting sections:
' - blank cells, or containing spaces only
' - same value repeated
' - cells containing "total"
'
' Files are saved in a "Split" subfolder from the location of the source workbook, and named after the section name.

Dim osh As Worksheet ' Original sheet
Dim iRow As Long ' Cursors
Dim iCol As Long
Dim iFirstRow As Long ' Constant
Dim iTotalRows As Long ' Constant
Dim iStartRow As Long ' Section delimiters
Dim iStopRow As Long
Dim sSectionName As String ' Section name (and filename)
Dim rCell As Range ' current cell
Dim owb As Workbook ' Original workbook
Dim sFilePath As String ' Constant
Dim iCount As Integer ' # of documents created

iCol = Application.InputBox("Enter the column number used for splitting", "Select column", 2, , , , , 1)
iRow = Application.InputBox("Enter the starting row number (to skip header)", "Select row", 2, , , , , 1)
iFirstRow = iRow

Set osh = Application.ActiveSheet
Set owb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
iTotalRows = osh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
sFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

If Dir(sFilePath + "\Split", vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir sFilePath + "\Split"
End If

'Turn Off Screen Updating  Events
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do
    ' Get cell at cursor
    Set rCell = osh.Cells(iRow, iCol)
    sCell = Replace(rCell.Text, " ", "")

    If sCell = "" Or (rCell.Text = sSectionName And iStartRow <> 0) Or InStr(1, rCell.Text, "total", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        ' Skip condition met
    Else
        ' Found new section
        If iStartRow = 0 Then
            ' StartRow delimiter not set, meaning beginning a new section
            sSectionName = rCell.Text
            iStartRow = iRow
        Else
            ' StartRow delimiter set, meaning we reached the end of a section
            iStopRow = iRow - 1

            ' Pass variables to a separate sub to create and save the new worksheet
            CopySheet osh, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, owb.fileFormat
            iCount = iCount + 1

            ' Reset section delimiters
            iStartRow = 0
            iStopRow = 0

            ' Ready to continue loop
            iRow = iRow - 1
        End If
    End If

    ' Continue until last row is reached
    If iRow < iTotalRows Then
            iRow = iRow + 1
    Else
        ' Finished. Save the last section
        iStopRow = iRow
        CopySheet osh, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, owb.fileFormat
        iCount = iCount + 1

        ' Exit
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

'Turn On Screen Updating  Events
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox Str(iCount) + " documents saved in " + sFilePath


End Sub

Public Sub DeleteRows(targetSheet As Worksheet, RowFrom As Long, RowTo As Long)

Dim rngRange As Range
Set rngRange = Range(targetSheet.Cells(RowFrom, 1), targetSheet.Cells(RowTo, 1)).EntireRow
rngRange.Select
rngRange.Delete

End Sub


Public Sub CopySheet(osh As Worksheet, iFirstRow As Long, iStartRow As Long, iStopRow As Long, iTotalRows As Long, sFilePath As String, sSectionName As String, fileFormat As XlFileFormat)
     Dim ash As Worksheet ' Copied sheet
     Dim awb As Workbook ' New workbook

     ' Copy book
     osh.Copy
     Set ash = Application.ActiveSheet

     ' Delete Rows after section
     If iTotalRows > iStopRow Then
         DeleteRows ash, iStopRow + 1, iTotalRows
     End If

     ' Delete Rows before section
     If iStartRow > iFirstRow Then
         DeleteRows ash, iFirstRow, iStartRow - 1
     End If

     ' Select left-topmost cell
     ash.Cells(1, 1).Select

     ' Clean up a few characters to prevent invalid filename
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "/", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "\", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ":", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "=", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "*", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ".", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "?", " ")
     sSectionName = Strings.Trim(sSectionName)

     ' Save in same format as original workbook
     ash.SaveAs sFilePath + "\Split\" + sSectionName + "_manager_breakout", fileFormat

     ' Close
     Set awb = ash.Parent
     awb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Rule of thumb, if your variables need an explanatory comment, then they have a bad name. Drop these useless Hungarian prefixes and spell out `originalSheet` and `documentsCreated`, and rename the others so that the comment becomes redundant and can be removed. Use meaningful names, and thank yourself later. Also consider moving the declarations closer to where they're actually assigned - having a wall of declarations at the top of a procedure isn't practical or useful in any way, and makes it harder than needed to spot an unused variable.

Comment: That said, if you're asking how to copy worksheets to a specific workbook, there should be well over a thousand existing posts on the topic that can help you get that to work. As for where it needs to go, you can try placing a breakpoint (F9) in the code, and using step-through (F8) to execute the code line by line, see where it's at, and determine at what point you want that to happen. ....we can't guess that for you.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the feedback. I found that the existing questions that answer how to copy worksheets don't allow me to preserve the links between my data sheet and summary sheet. I want to keep the links between the sheets and not have all the new workbooks referencing the original workbook.

Comment: Huh? Either you keep the links, **or** you have the new books referencing the old one. Can't have your cake and eat it too!

Comment: I do want the links between sheets. Right now I have the original workbook with sheet 1 - data and sheet 2 - summary. Sheet 2 has links to sheet 1. I can get to new split out workbooks with sheet 1 split out the way I want and then a sheet 2 copy 
 but it's linked to the original workbook's sheet 1 and I want it linked to sheet 1 that is in the newly created worksheet. What I have copies the data range and moves it to a new worksheet so I get a type mismatch error if I try to copy the range and worksheet together. I believe I have to move the range and sheet together to maintain the links.

Comment: Try doing it manually first, it'll give you an idea of how to go about doing it with code (use the macro recorder if needed)